# How to connect the IDs referenced in XML data to the corresponding ID in another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

So here is an example of what the XML data looks like in the `STUDIES` table in database 2:

```
c="status_id" o="1009" n="1006" />
```

However, it's not really useful to a user. "What is a status of 1009?"

There is a `STATUSES` table in database 1 that gives a value for this `ID` (1009 = DRAFT.)

How can I phrase a query so that the output is in text instead of IDs or numbers? So instead of USER_ID=3 and STATUS_ID=1009, I want John Smith and DRAFT. As mentioned above this will need to cross multiple tables and databases but on the same server.

Let me know if I can provide more information.

Edit to question on 8/30:

Database 1 called "dbrad" has 3 tables called "STATUSES", "STUDIES", and "USERS".

The other database is called "dbrad.audit". It has 1 table called "STUDIES". Within this table are 4 rows:
PK: The number in this is the study ID from the STUDIES table of the dbrad db
USER ID: The number is this row is the user id from the USERS table of the dbrad db
DT: This is the date/time that the action occured. This value is only in this table
DATA: This is the action that transpired like in my original example. So maybe a study changed status or a stat was removed, whatever. The only data I really care about is the status. This number is from the STATUS table in the dbrad db.

So it will look like this in the dbrad.audit db:
PK   USER_ID       DT       DATA

---|----------|-----------|-----

123  456       2015-08-30   c="status_id" o="1009" n="1005"

What I want is query that will automatically match this data to its corresponding table in the other database and output in a form that makes sense. So I would get:

PK   USER_ID            DT        DATA

----|------------|--------------|-------

MR       John      2015-08-30     o=Draft n=Read

Let me know if this helps

Comment: What data type is this data stored in? is it `XML` or `VARCHAR`? We canot pose a solution without this kind of info.

Comment: @ServerSurfer FYI, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Hey Nick, not sure. It might be VARCHAR since I'm not seeing a character limit or anything. However when I hover over the data in the DB, it says "Click to show in XML Editor". Anything I can provide to check this? I didn't create the DB; just trying to make a report of the data that's in it.

Comment: @har07 Thanks, Har. First time posting on the site so I'll make sure to include these notes in the future.

Comment: Sounds like its XML. I don't know what tool you're using but if its SSMS you can use the object browser to drill and see what data type the column is or you can type `sp_help '<your table>'`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Reaction on new information given by ServerSurver in his edits:

First of all: Your expression `c="status_id" o="1009" n="1006" /> is no valid XML. An XML-Element has an element name and may have attributes

```
<MyElement attribut1="1" Another="hello">
```

Obviously your expression are some attributes of an XML Element. Is this Element "alone" or part of a bigger structure?

How many different statuses do you have in your table?

If you want to connect tables (very often do get exactly what you want: A caption for an ID value) you have to join them. If you are sure, that all values exist in the catalog table (your "STATUSES"), it will be an INNER JOIN, otherwise probably a LEFT JOIN.

This JOIN is followed by an "ON" which informs SQL Server on which value-match the join is done. So you must provide one field from the "left" and one from the "right" table with fitting data types.

My exampel cannot fit to your data exactly. I do not know enough...

First of all I declare a virtual table @statuses. Within the SELECT you have to replace this by your real table (probably `dbrad.dbo.STATUSES"`).

I assume, that your XML has a `root node` and its element name is `item`. You must change this in the way it is with you. The two INNER JOINs inform SQL Server that the attribut `o` is to be mapped to STATUSES, same with the attribut `n`.

The SELECT itself can use this information...

It looks bit "manual" 'cause I do not know your data...

```
declare @statuses TABLE(ID INT, caption VARCHAR(100));
insert into @statuses VALUES(1009,'DRAFT'),(1006,'another Status');

declare @x XML='<root><item c="status_id" o="1009" n="1006" /></root>';

SELECT item.x.value('@c','varchar(max)') AS ValueCaption
      ,item.x.value('@o','int') AS o_value
      ,o_st.caption AS o_Caption
      ,item.x.value('@n','int') AS n_value
      ,n_st.caption AS n_Caption
FROM @x.nodes('/root/item') AS item(x)
INNER JOIN @statuses AS o_st ON o_st.ID=item.x.value('@o','int')
INNER JOIN @statuses AS n_st ON n_st.ID=item.x.value('@n','int')
```

Result: status_id | 1009 | DRAFT | 1006 | another Status

Comment: Thanks, Shnugo; appreciate your time on this however this looks a bit "manual". It appears I have to declare what all the IDs are instead of the system making the reference. I'll try to explain the architecture better.

Comment: @ServerSurfer, XML is so variable, that it needs some manual declarations to fix this. Maybe give some further information about your structures and how you want to query them.

Comment: @ServerSurfer, edited my answer. I hope you understand what I'm talking about... Please vote up and/or mark as accepted if helpful, thx!